# Incredibly slow conversion (Java)

Tags: java, type-conversion

In my software I generate an image (by scaling multiple images and merging them) and then I should convert it to `InputStream` like:

```
InputStream toInputStream(BufferedImage picture) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(picture, "png", os);                       //up to 15 seconds
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
}
```

But second line of this method takes up to 15 seconds to complete! For comparison, the whole image is being generated in 1.4 seconds. Why is it so incredibly slow? Is it other way to convert `BufferedImage` to `InputSream` quicklier?

**UPD:**

I wrote a test method:

```
void ConversionTest(){
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\1.png"));
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Started");
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", os);
        System.out.println("Ended in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) +" ms");
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

[My sample file](http://dropmefiles.com/jipWu)

Takes 9113 ms on my pc.

Comment: It's possible that it has to recopy a large chunk of the image multiple times when it resizes the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. What's the size after you call `ImageIO.write`?

Comment: @resueman `os.size()` returns 5292595

Comment: That shouldn't cause that much of a slowdown then. You could try changing the contructor to `ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(5292595)` and see if it helps though.

Comment: Could you try writing to a `FileOutputStream`, then retrieve the bytes from a `FileInputStream` ?

Comment: @resueman But this size may vary. I don't know it in advance.

Comment: @AndrewR If that is the cause, just having it be in the same ballpark as the correct value would help. If you test it with a large initial buffer and it helps, the size of the `BufferedImage` could be used to estimate the needed size.

Comment: @Berger No, it takes the same 15 seconds.

Comment: @resueman Used the same picture and the same size. Still no effect.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to troubleshoot if you could share the image with us that you’re trying to read.  It might also be useful to know what Java version you’re using.

Comment: @VGR Added test method and sample picture to the question.

Comment: So you read an image using `ImageIO.read`, write that to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then create a `ByteArrayInputStream` just to get something that implements `InputStream`? This also copies a lot of data (i.e the image bytes). Have you tried this "shortcut" already: [How to convert BufferedImage to InputStream?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4251451) ?

Comment: That method took exactly 1400 milliseconds for me, using Java 1.8.0_111 64-bit in Windows 7.

Comment: @VGR That's really strange. My configurations are Java 1.8 on Windows 10 64 bit (9100 ms) and Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian (14000 ms)

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are your BufferedImages coming from in your application?  Are you drawing them, or just reading them from somewhere?  If it’s the latter, there is no reason to use ImageIO or ByteArrayOutputStream; you can just return the InputStream corresponding to the original source.

Comment: @VGR As I specified in the question, they are generated by scaling and merging images using `Graphics2D` class. So I need to get the `InputStream` exactly from the `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Oops, sorry, so you did.

Comment: @Tom Trying to implement this trick now. But this expression doesn't return proper stream: somehow its content is several times bigger than it should be: 34 MB vs 5.9 MB.

Comment: @AndrewR Well, it *should* contain the same data as the result of `ImageIO.write`. When you write that "other" byte array (from the "shortcut"), is it a valid working picture? If so, then the 34MB version might be an uncompressed one, where is 5.9MB are compressed using *png*. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @Tom You are right. Exact size of raster is 34560000 = 3600 x 2400 x 4 bytes. It's the uncompressed image, so unfortunately it is not what I need.

Comment: Too bad, but it was worth to test it :D.